# Merge 2 arrays of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have 2 arrays of objects and I want to merge their objects in parallel manner.
For example

```
var array = [{foo: 2} , {boo: 3}]
var array2 = [{foo2: 2}, {boo2: 4}]
```

The result will be

```
var array3 = [{foo:2,foo2:2},{boo:3,boo2:4}]
```

How can I do it in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse through one array and pick one item and pick the item from the another array and then merge them.

```js
var array = [{foo: 2} , {boo: 3}];
var array2 = [{foo2: 2}, {boo2: 4}];

var _o = array.map(function(obj1, i){
  
  var obj2 = array2[i];
  for (var attrname in obj2) { obj1[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
  return obj1;

});

// _o is the final array

alert(JSON.stringify(_o));
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for the merge.

```
array.map((obj,index) => Object.assign(obj,array2[index]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look a lodash:

```js
var users = {
  'data': [{ 'user': 'barney' }, { 'user': 'fred' }]
};

var ages = {
  'data': [{ 'age': 36 }, { 'age': 40 }]
};

_.merge(users, ages);
// → { 'data': [{ 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 }] }
```

[Lodash doc for merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)

Comment: of course, but you need to implement it yourself then

Comment: then why **lodash**? As OP doesn't tagged lodash.